# After execution....the first part of the program doesn't run. Not only that the loop ends without moving into the selected menu

Tags: python

```py
CH = 'y' or 'Y'
while (CH!='n'):
    
    print('WELCOME TO MAX FASHION')
    print('1.MOVE INTO FACULTY ACOUNT')
    print('2.MOVE INTO STANDARD ACCOUNT')
    ch=input('enter your choice:')
    if ch==1:
        FACULTY_MENU()
    elif ch==2:
        STANDARD_MENU()
    else:
        break
    print('DO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE Y \ N ?')
    CH=input('enter your choice : ')
```

There is a former part for this program...and this is the last part.
When executed the program runs from this part instead of the first and doesn't move into the chosen table but merely ends the program

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `input` returns a string. You are comparing that to integers in your `if` statements. The means it will always hit your last `else` and then proceed `break` your `while` statement.

You need to either cast the choice as a string, or change your `if` statements to compare with strings.

On a sidenote, I would neveer use `CH` and `ch` that close together. It will confuse you when reading this code a week from now.

```py
def FACULTY_MENU():
    print("FACULTY_MENU")


def STANDARD_MENU():
    print("STANDARD_MENU")


choice_continue = "y" or "Y"


while choice_continue != "n":
    print("WELCOME TO MAX FASHION")
    print("  1. MOVE INTO FACULTY ACOUNT")
    print("  2. MOVE INTO STANDARD ACCOUNT")
    choice_main = input("enter your choice:")
    print(type(choice_main))

    if choice_main == "1":
        FACULTY_MENU()
    elif choice_main == "2":
        STANDARD_MENU()
    else:
        break
    choice_continue = input("DO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE Y \ N ?")
```